# Code Igniter / Pyro CMS Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I have just downloaded a git of a site running on Pyro CMS on the Code Igniter PHP framework and tried to run it locally however it is throwing this error:

```
[Mon Jul 24 10:05:39.868253 2017] [:error] [pid 5944:tid 1944] [client ::1:55468] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\system\\codeigniter\\database\\DB_driver.php on line 831
```

I have tried using result() rather than result_array() however it throws the same error.

The site is running on PHP version 5.6.31 on an XAMPP local server.

Below is the file which is throwing the error:

https://pastebin.com/QXSUD5u6

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party here but usually that happens in codeigniter when there is no database connection. Check the database config file to make sure it is properly set up for your local host credentials; my guess is that it is still configured to access the 'online' database from which you downloaded the files.